# Differentiability of $|x|$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Why does the continuous function $f(x) = |x|$ fails to have tangent line at $x=0$ ? Concluding that the function is not differentiable at $x=0$

In fact, the continuous function $|x-a|$ has a global minimum at $x=a$.
Then it (must?) also mean that the function has a zero slope at $x=a±\epsilon$, as we let $\epsilon$ approach $0$.

This then implies that it is differentiability at that point without solely relying on its continuity since it (has?) a tangent line at the said point.

I do not have a good background on real analysis and I would appreciate it if anyone would point out the loophole in my knowledge.

Comment: It have different  tangent lines from left and right i.e. left derivative not equal right, so derivative and tangent not exist.

Comment: minima/maxima occur at critical points, which is where the derivative is 0 OR undefined.   it is undefined here, as per the answer below,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto|x|$ does indeed have a global minimum at $0$, but this simply means that $|0|\le|x|$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Note that the definition of "global minimum" makes no reference to differentiability. While it is true that if $f$ has a global minimum at $a$, *and* $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f'(a)=0$, this theorem says nothing about what happens when $f$ is *not* differentiable at $a$.

Comment: Or more precisely, it says nothing about whether $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Obviously, when it isn't, $f^\prime(a)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lemma of analysis that the limit exists if and only if the left and right limit exists. You might be interested in verifying that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} |x|/x = 1$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} |x|/x = -1$$

Thereby demonstrating that there is no well defined derivative at 0.

Comment: may I ask what does the function $g(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$ imply on $f(x) = |x|$? All I know is that if $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ is differentiable of the class N, then composite function $a(b(x))$ is also class N differentiable. Does it also holds true for the converse (non-differentiable)?

Comment: It would also be required that the left and right limits agree.

Comment: @Yami look up the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Yami: "In fact, the continuous function y= |x- a| has an absolute minimum at x= a.  Then it (must?) also mean that the function must have 0 slope at $x= a\pm \epsilon$ as we let $\epsilon$ approach 0"

NO! That would require that the function be differentiable, not just continuous at x= a.

Here y= x for all x> 0 so y'= 1 for all x> 0.  Since y= -x for all x< 0, y'= -1 for all x< 0.  A derivative is not necessarily continuous but it does always have the "intermediate value" property":  if y' has value a at one point and value b at another then y' takes on all values between a and b at some point between those two points.  With y'= 1 for all x> 0 and y'= -1 for all x< 0, we **can't** have y' taking on all values between -1 and 1 at the single point x= 0 so the function cannot have a derivative at x= 0..